# Removing all values in Notepad++ except those in square brackets

Tags: notepad++

I'm taking on a task that involves extracting time values from a block of text in Notepad++ looking to strip away the extra text, but keep the times in square brackets.

Would want to change this:

```
[00:08.41] lorem ipsum
[00:13.17] lorem ipsum
[00:18.79] lorem ipsum
[00:23.33] lorem ipsum

[00:33.75] lorem ipsum
[00:44.10] lorem ipsum

[01:57.11] lorem ipsum [02:02.54]
```

Into:

```
[00:08.41]
[00:13.17]
[00:18.79]
[00:23.33]

[00:33.75]
[00:44.10] 

[01:57.11][02:02.54]
```

My manager gave me this string, but it seems there's something wrong with it and it won't work

```
(?:^|(?<=]))[^][]*?(?=[|$)
```

Comment: You have to escape the square bracket in the lookahead like `(?=\[|$)` but consider using the posted answer without lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[.+?](*SKIP)(*F)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[.+?]          # something in square brackets
(*SKIP)(*F)     # forget them
|               # OR
.               # 1 or more any character but newline
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Yes, you're right.